# Selenium C# - Unable to find element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

At first I created a code in Selenium IDE firefox addon which is scraping a data from website. Of course it is working properly in IDE.

I want to scrape url from this:

```
<div class="gs-per-result-labels" url="http://example.com/foo/bar"></div>
```

As HTML is is shown as:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://example.com</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>//div[@class='gs-per-result-labels']@url</td>
    <td>myValue</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${myValue}</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
```

Both command are executing properly and `echo` is giving right value. Next I changed format to `C# / NUnit / WebDriver` and I copied code to Visual Studio 2015. I added `FirefoxDriver` and `IWebDriver` references. That is the code:

```
private static IWebDriver driver;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    string myValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='gs-per-result-labels']")).GetAttribute("url");
}
```

I also added `Sleep` to be sure that the page is fully loaded when it comes to scraping value. The thing is I am getting error on `FindElement` function, because `driver` was unable to find element. I am wondering why does that happen. Everything seems to be the same. Do you have any tips?

I think it is worth to said: The content which I want to scrape is generated by php or javascript (thats are google search result on "example" page which is not google)

Comment: Your HTML sample doesn't contain any `div`s. Is that intentional?

Comment: There is `//div[@class='gs-per-result-labels']`

Comment: So XPath queries XML, that query `//div[@class='gs-per-result-labels']` will look for `div` elements with a `class` attribute, with the value `'gs-per-result-labels'`. It will not do a plain text search of the HTML body.

Comment: I am not sure you understand me. This is working properly: https://puu.sh/td68I/8d0a8d65ba.png

But when I do the same in c# (I even use auto generated code by Selenium IDE) I cant get the `url` attribute.

Comment: I see, your edit makes it a little more clear. I would just remove that HTML all together, it seems unrelated to your issue and will just confuse. Could you try `By.ByClassName("gs-per-result-labels")` just to rule out any problems with the XPath query. I think the 10 second sleep rules out any chance the page isn't ready.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to check if the Xpath is absolutely correct. You can always use Firebug or if you want to do it programmatically, below lines should help

```
 List<WebElement> existList=driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='gs-per-result-labels']"));
 if(existList.size()>0){
    //SOPL("element present");
 }
```

I would suggest you to use explicit wait

```
 WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait (driver,60);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("//div[@class='gs-per-result-labels']")));
  string myValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='gs-per-result-labels']")).GetAttribute("url");
```